Как получит всю информацию о юзере по id в Django?
У меня от юзера есть только его id, как найти остальную инфу?
Пытался вот так сделать:
user = User.objects.get(id)

но выдает:
"TypeError at /polls/user/1/
cannot unpack non-iterable int object"


...get(pk=id)?

user = User.objects.get(id=id)

или
user = User.objects.get(pk=id)

если нужная информация в одной модели (таблице), то user передать в шаблон, в шаблоне:
{{user.fieldname}}

